# Get selection Number from GWT Highcharts

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I have areacharts with 2 series. Each of both has the same data, but different values. When I select one of the point, I want to know index of point. For example. when I select first point, I want take "1" and so on. Like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLFRG/).

For instance they used

```
formatter: function() {
 return 'point ' + this.point.myIndex;
```

}

but it is for javascript

`formatter: function() {
     return 'point ' + this.point.myIndex;
}`

Does anybody know how to do it from gwt wrapper Moxie Apps GWT Highcharts?